# Accessing an image resource by name and assigning it to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, picturebox

I have this list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("dog.jpg");
list.Add("cat.jpg");
list.Add("horse.jpg");
```

In my resources, I have 3 images named: dog, cat, and horse. I want to display them in a picture box using the list.

I have tried something like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = project.Properties.Resources.list[2]; // should display the horse image
```

The problem is that it displays the error:

> 'Resources' does not contain a definition for 'list' `

How can I get the image using the name in the list?

Comment: How have you defined Image in the resources? Can you put screen shot? or xml?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how you can refer to the resources. You're implicitly expecting `list[2]` to be replaced by its string value, and then parsed as if it were referring to an existing resource. This simply doesn't work in C# (without reflection, which you should not start using!).

Comment: It would appear you'd be better off placing your images in a folder of the project and loading all of the images that way. Then you'd have an array of the images that you could set using an indexer like you're trying above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties.Resources only knows the resources (dog, cat, and horse) so you can't give him a string and expect him to know the resource.
You need to use the GetObject method from the ResourceManager like this:

```
(Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(list[2])
```

This should give you the horse image.

Answer (score 2):

When you add images, strings, etc. to a resource file (.resx), Visual Studio  automatically generates strongly-typed properties in the corresponding `Resources` class for you.  So for example, if you added `horse.jpg` to `Resources.resx` in your project, there should be a `horse` property on the `Properties.Resources` class which returns a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.  So you should be able to do:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.horse;
```

If you want to be able to access an image resource by name, then you can do it the same way the generated code does it, using `ResourceManager.GetObject`.  But note the image resource name will not include the `.jpg` extension and you will have to cast the result to a `Bitmap`:

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("horse");
```

You could create a helper method which will strip the extension off the filename and retrieve the resource, like this:

```
private Bitmap GetImageResource(string filename)
{
    string resourceName = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf("."));
    return (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName);
}
```

That would allow you to use it with your list like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImageResource(list[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling pictureBox1.Refresh(); after assigning the image.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think that issue is that it is looking for the image named "list[2]" rather than looking inside for "horse".

Comment: @VladAndrei: You're correct about the core of the issue. But what you're trying to do now simply isn't possible in C#. The concept of "variable variable names" (e.g. in PHP,  if `$varname = "foo"`, then `$$varname` refers to the `$foo` variable) does not exist in C#.