# Parse Resources

Tags: c#

I have several images in Resources part of a project.
Each image is called **img_1.png**, **img_2.png**, **img_3.png**, etc

I have a **pictureBox** and depending of the value of an **index** I would like to display a different picture. If **index**=1, then display **img_1.png**, etc

Is there a way to access content of Resources with a variable. Something like the following code (which doesn't work)

`myPictureBox.Image = myProject.Properties.Resources.img_ + index.ToString() + ".png";`

Comment: there are multiple ways to do. provide some codes (like how you store the resource, resource type, how to get the resource) and i can help you with this

Comment: @Jacky I have completed the question to precise image are png. What part of code would you need ? myPictureBox is Winform and I have added images to the resources using Visual Studio (in Property of the project, Ressources, add ressources)

Comment: there is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1192054/1132334), [one of its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192077/1132334) specifically offers a solution where the name of the resource is variable at runtime.

Comment: Please do not use the `visual-studio` tag unless your question is pertaining to the Visual Studio IDE, rather than code simply developed in it. Are you using a Resources file?

Comment: If you're using a Resources file, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592576/accessing-an-image-resource-by-name-and-assigning-it-to-a-picturebox) should answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
myPictureBox.Image = myProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"img_{index}");
```